# Поделить и вывести строки из Oracle ДБ в 4 колонны

Tags: php, oracle

Есть Select query от Oracle базы. Нужно Фетчнутые строки поделить на 4 строки и вывести на экран. Вроде этого:

`Item 1     Item 2     Item 3      Item 4 
Item 5     Item 6     Item 7      Item 8
Item 9     Item 10    Item 11     Item 12
Item 13.......`

Какую логигу можете мне предложить? Что бы я не писал,то в один роу не помещаются, то вообще нету половины.

Вот моя код для 2-х колон, но не знаю как сделать последовательно на 4 колонны

```html
<?php
$stmt1 = oci_parse($conn, $query1);
oci_execute($stmt1);
$mssqlaray = array();
$index = 0;
while (($row1 = oci_fetch_array($stmt1, OCI_BOTH))) 
{
  $mssqlaray[$index] = $row1;
    $index++;
}

for($j = 0; $j < oci_num_rows($stmt1); $j+=2)
{
  echo '
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'">'.$mssqlaray[$j][1].'   </label>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
for($j = 1; $j < oci_num_rows($stmt1); $j+=2)
{
    echo '
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'"type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox1'.$mssqlaray[$j][0].'">'.$mssqlaray[$j][1].'</label>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: А вы покажите, что вы пишите. И вообще плохо понятно, что должно получиться

Comment: `array_chunk`  вам в помощь

Comment: @Viktorov Я выложил код где разбил дату на 2 колонны, но мне нужно разделить на 4.

Comment: @teran попробую

Answer (score 0):

Одно из найденных решений

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  first<input type="checkbox" name="first[0][value]" id="first[]" value="first" />
  <input type="hidden" name="first[0][id]" value="first[]"> second
  <input type="checkbox" name="first[1][value]" id="second[]" value="second" />
  <input type="hidden" name="first[1][id]" value="second[]"> third
  <input type="checkbox" name="first[2][value]" id="third[]" value="third" />
  <input type="hidden" name="first[2][id]" value="third[]">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

PHP часть

```html
foreach($_POST['first'] as $value){
  echo 'VALUE: '.$value['value'].'<br/>';
  echo 'ID: '.$value['id'].'<br/>';
}
```